# GeoDjango saving empty fields

Tags: mysql, django, geodjango

Alright, why is it that I can't save empty values to a Point-, MultiPoint- or PolygonField?

I created a form where users can select an area or location where they spotted a specific bird species. To store the data I use GeoDjango, the data can be stored in a PointField or PolygonField.

The PointField however is not required, so in the forms I set required to False which gives me the following error;

For the record, I am using MySQL as a database. I currently don't need all the extra features PostgreSQL comes with.

```
IntegrityError at /sighting/where-did-you-spot-the-bird/

(1048, "Column 'sighting' cannot be null")
```

#models.py

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

class Sighting(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    description = models.TextField()
    sighting = models.PointField(
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        spatial_index=False
    )
```

So the column sighting cannot be null, why is that? Am I missing something or is a value always required?

One solution would be to save a default value, let's say Point(0,0) but their should be another solution.

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

MySQL doesn't allow empty spatial fields (known pitfall: https://www.buzzphp.com/posts/geodjango-mysql-points-cant-be-null-what-other-empty-value-should-i-use)

Either add a `default` of an empty `Point()` or a point with lat/long `0,0`:

```
class Sighting(models.Model)
    sighting = models.PointField(
        blank=True,
        spatial_index=False,
        default=Point(0, 0)  # or Point([]) if allowed
)
```

Or consider changing to PostgresSQL with PostGIS: When we are using GIS, almost by definition we are going to use big data and PostgreSQL is vastly more suited for that role. (example article: https://www.enterprisedb.com/blog/postgresql-vs-mysql-360-degree-comparison-syntax-performance-scalability-and-features)

Comment: Well, I was aware that their is limited functionality using MySQL, like not being able to set a custom SRID but I did not know it doesn't allow for empty spatial fields. I'm currently using a default Point and will filter this out later on. Thank you for the clarification!